# WPF , How to change the background color of the "main window" from "Setting window"?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I wrote a **WPF** program where I want to **change** the **background color** of the main window using the **settings window**.
Project requirements:

**1-** The settings window should be able to save the colors in a variable and display those colors again the moment the settings window is opened again.

**2-** The background color of the main window should be perfectly Binding to the colors in the settings window, which will be applied immediately when changes are made.

[My WPF Project](https://github.com/KeyvanSFX/RectChangeColor)

**I tried several methods including:**

**1-** I defined a global variable of type LinearGradientBrush in the code behind the main window.

**2-** I defined a global variable of type LinearGradientBrush in the app.xaml file.

But none of these methods worked properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found A Project That Is Exactly What I Imagined In My Mind.
I Put The Source Link Of The Project Here.

[Project Solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33001/WPF-A-Simple-Color-Picker-With-Preview)

[image: First Project Preview]

Answer (score 2):

1. You basically have to define a brush resource. This example will define this resource in the *App.xaml*.
   Name it e.g. "MainWindowBackgroudBrush":

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainWindowBackgroudBrush"
                   Color="Orange" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

2. Reference this resource from your `MainWindow` (or in general the `Control` that should have the dynamic background) using `DynamicResource`. `DynamicResource` indicates that the referenced resource is expected to change during runtime (i.e. the resource is dynamic):

```xml
<Window Background="{DynamicResource MainWindowBackgroudBrush}">
</Window>
```

3. Then modify the brush resource from anywhere e.g.,  from your `SettingsWindow` using the static `Application.Current` property:

```cs
Application.Current.Resources["MainWindowBackgroudBrush"] = Brushes.Red;
```

---

In case of a `GradientBrush` or when you want to change the colors of a `Brush` in general, you must either create and replace a complete new `Brush` dynamically or just reference a `Color` instead of the complete `Brush`.

To allow modification of dynamic resources from e.g. clients of your library (who usually don't know the actual resource keys) you would define a `static` `ComponentResourceKey` which you would use instead of the magic string (for registering and for referencing the resource).

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class App : Application
{
  public static ComponentResourceKey StartColorKey { get; } = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(App), "StartColor");
  public static ComponentResourceKey EndColorKey { get; } = new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(App), "EndColor");
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Color x:Key="{x:Static local:App.StartColorKey}">Orange</Color>
  <Color x:Key="{x:Static local:App.EndColorKey}">Green</Color>

  <!-- Example on how to create brushes from Color resources -->
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainWindowBackgroundBrush"
                   Color="{StaticResource {x:Static local:App.StartColorKey}}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                         StartPoint="0.5,0">
      <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:App.StartColorKey}}"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:App.EndColorKey}}"
                    Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Window.Background>
</Window>
```

```cs
// Replace the resource at runtime
Application.Current.Resources[App.StartColorKey] = Brushes.Red;
```

### Remarks

Because `DynamicResource` instructs the XAML engine to explicitly track the referenced resource for changes, the engine won't track changes to properties of a nested objects (for example `LinearGradientBrush.GradientStopes.GradientStop`) of the tracked resource.

For this reason the following example won't work: changes to the dynamic `Color` resource, referenced by a `SolidColorBrush`, won't be detected by elements that reference this `SolidColorBrush` (because the `SolidColorBrush` resource itself hasn't changed. Only the nested property `SolidColorBrush.Color`):
**App.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Color x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor}">Orange</Color>

  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundBrush"
                   Color="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Button Background="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}" />
</Window>
```

To make it work, you must directly reference the dynamic resource. This way the XAML engine will track changes. You do this by defining the referencing object, in this case the `SolidColorBrush`, inline:
**App.xaml**

```xml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Color x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor}">Orange</Color>

  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroudBrush"
                   Color="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Button>
    <Button.Background>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundColor}" />
    </Button.Background>
  </Button>
</Window>
```

This is especially useful for complex objects like a `GradientBrush`, where you want to avoid to construct the complete object when the resource referenced by a nested property changes.

Comment: Nice done, but in that case, nothing will be saved when restarting application, right?

Comment: Yes. But that's a requirement that was not asked for

Comment: I Use "<GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Color, Source={StaticResource StartColorBackground}}" In MainWindows And "Fill="{DynamicResource StartColorBackground}" In SettingWindows But When I Change Color From Window of Settings , The Background color Of Main Not Changed

Comment: That's not much information. The Property Fill is usually off your Brush. Their there might be a type mismatch here as you seen to bind a Color to this property

Comment: I have uploaded the latest project changes to GitHub [Project Link](https://github.com/KeyvanSFX/RectChangeColor) Check It Please.

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain the issue and to show how to solve it. It also shows the recommended pattern for dynamic resource declarations.

Answer (score -2):

In visual studio go to your Properties window.
Navigate to settings, add a parameter of type color and give it a name like yourColor
now if you change your color store it in the settings file:

```
properties.settings.default.yourColor = newBackgroundColor;
properties.settings.default.save();
```

wenn you start you window look in your properties and use it as background.

```
this.background = properties.settings.default.yourColor;
```

(pseudocode wont compile)